# Set Select in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I`ve been trying to work out how to fix this problem in vain.

Here the below code works fine. However, in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oo0eshhj/) nothing happens as well as in HTML file.

I don`t know what is wrong with it.  Could anyone please show me how I can fix it?

```js
function selectItems() { 
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("car-select");
    var array = ["McLaren", "Ferrari", "Mercedes"];
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", "Car");
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
        option.text = array[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }

    var myDiv2 = document.getElementById("tyre-select");
    var array2 = ["Bridgestone", "Michelin", "Continental"];
    var selectList2 = document.createElement("select");
    selectList2.setAttribute("id", "Eng");
    myDiv2.appendChild(selectList2);
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.setAttribute("value", array2[i]);
        option2.text = array2[i];
        selectList2.appendChild(option2);
    }
}
```

```html
<body class="car-showing" onload="selectItems()">
    <div id="PPMCar">
        <form method="post">    
            <ul> 
              <li class="engine-item"> 
                    <div class="engine-details-name">                 
                        <a class="race-team">Race Team</a>
                        <ul class="car-attributes">
                            <div id="car-select">
                                <li>#1:</li>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tyre-select">
                                <li>#2:</li>
                            </div>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Working fine..https://jsfiddle.net/oo0eshhj/1/ Change the load type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine for me, and really there's nothing wrong with Michael Gaskill's code, I am just someone who if I see the same code being implemented more than once, I work to find a way to not have to repeat myself.

This way declares a function inside our function. The resulting code accomplishes the same thing, but ends up gaining some description as well as removing a lot of redundant processes.

```js
function selectItems() {
  var fn = function(el,select_id, arr) {
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", select_id);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
      option.text = arr[i];
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    el.appendChild(selectList);
  };
  var car_select = document.getElementById("car-select");
  var car_brands = ["McLaren", "Ferrari", "Mercedes"];
  fn(car_select, 'car', car_brands);

  var tyre_select = document.getElementById("tyre-select");
  var tyre_brands = ["Bridgestone", "Michelin", "Continental"];
  fn(tyre_select, 'tyre', tyre_brands);
}
```

```html
<body class="car-showing" onload="selectItems()">
  <div id="PPMCar">
    <form method="post">
      <ul>
        <li class="engine-item">
          <div class="engine-details-name">
            <a class="race-team">Race Team</a>
            <ul class="car-attributes">
              <div id="car-select">
                <li>#1:</li>
              </div>
              <div id="tyre-select">
                <li>#2:</li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Edit

To speak on my comment on Gaskill's code, you could do this with jQuery, *if* you are using it:

```js
function selectItems() {

  var create_select = function(parent, select_id, options) {

    var select = $('<select />', {
      id: select_id,
      name: select_id
    });

    options = options.map(function(el, i) {
      return $('<option />', {
        value: el,
        html: el
      });
    });
    select.append(options).appendTo($(parent));

  };

  var car_select = $("#car-select");
  var car_brands = ["McLaren", "Ferrari", "Mercedes"];
  create_select(car_select, 'car', car_brands);


  var tyre_select = document.getElementById("tyre-select");
  var tyre_brands = ["Bridgestone", "Michelin", "Continental"];
  create_select(tyre_select, 'tyre', tyre_brands);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="car-showing" onload="selectItems()">
  <div id="PPMCar">
    <form method="post">
      <ul>
        <li class="engine-item">
          <div class="engine-details-name">
            <a class="race-team">Race Team</a>
            <ul class="car-attributes">
              <div id="car-select">
                <li>#1:</li>
              </div>
              <div id="tyre-select">
                <li>#2:</li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I like the cut of your jib.  Good take on refactoring the example.

Answer (score 1):

Minor changes needed to get it to work:

```
function selectItems() { 
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("car-select");
    var array = ["McLaren", "Ferrari", "Mercedes"];
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", "Car");
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
        option.text = array[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    var myDiv2 = document.getElementById("tyre-select");
    var array2 = ["Bridgestone", "Michelin", "Continental"];
    var selectList2 = document.createElement("select");
    selectList2.setAttribute("id", "Eng");
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.setAttribute("value", array2[i]);
        option2.text = array2[i];
        selectList2.appendChild(option2);
    }
    myDiv2.appendChild(selectList2);
}

selectItems();
```

Append the `select` to the `div` after you append the `option` elements (prevents a stale DOM fragment).  Then make sure to call the `selectItems` function at the end to run the code.

Since you have the jQuery tag on the question, this same thing can be accomplished with less code and more easily with jQuery:

```
function selectItems() { 
    var array = ["McLaren", "Ferrari", "Mercedes"];
    var selectList = $("<select />").attr("id", "Car");
    $.each(array, function(index, item) {
        selectList.appendChild($("<option />").attr("value", array[i]).text(item));
    });
    $("#car-select").append(selectList);

    var array2 = ["Bridgestone", "Michelin", "Continental"];
    var selectList2 = $("#select").attr("id", "Eng");
    $.each(array2, function(index, item) {
        selectList2.appendChild($("<option />").attr("value", array2[i]).text(item));
    });
    $("#tyre-select").append(selectList2);
}

selectItems();
```

Comment: couldn't you just use `selectList.map` with jQuery?

Comment: Yep, you sure could, and that would be an improvement over the loop.  Great suggestion.  I'll update the answer with that.